# ng-blur how to not affect all html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to be able to click some part of page to not have it call the `hideAll` function

```
app.controller('NotificationController', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.visible = true;
   $scope.changeStatus = function(){
      $scope.visible = !$scope.visible; 
   };
   $scope.hideAll= function(){
      $scope.visible=false;
   };
});
```

Here is a link showing this:

```
<a href="#" ng-disabled="checked" ng-click="changeStatus()" ng-blur="hideAll()" class="button-default show-notifications js-show-notifications active">Press</a>
```

I want it so that when press on page this block I don't want to trigger the `blur`

```
<div class="notifications js-notifications" ng-init="visible=false" ng-show="visible">
....
</div>
```

Any idea how I make this work?

EDIT:

Full html:

```
    <li id="notifications" ng-app="notifications" ng-controller="NotificationController as notification">

        <a href="#" ng-disabled="checked" ng-click="changeStatus()" ng-blur="hideAll()" class="button-default show-notifications js-show-notifications active">
            <i class="fa fa-bell-o" style="font-size: 17px;">
            <div class="notifications-count js-count" data-count="<% notys.length %>"><% notys.length %></div>
          </i>
       </a>
        <div class="notifications js-notifications" ng-init="visible=false" ng-show="visible">
            <h3>Notifications</h3>
            <ul class="notifications-list">
                <li class="item no-data">You don't have notifications</li>
                <li ng-repeat="x in notys" class="item js-item" data-id="<% x.id %>">
                    <a href="<% x.project_id %>"  class="notification-link">
                    <div class="details">
                        <span class="title">New group created: <b> <% x.subject %> </b>. New project assigned to you <b> <% x.body %> </b></span>
                        <span class="date"><% x.created_at %></span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="show-all">Show all notifications</a>
        </div>
     </li>
```

Comment: Please explain expected behavior in more detail. Question is confusing. There is no blur shown associated with the `div.notifications` element so no reason it would trigger blur

Comment: I expect when click into `div.notifcations` element to not trigger `hideAll()` function... Now it trigger that function wherever click on page...

Comment: But that isn't what is shown in code...the `<a>` is only thing show with `hideAll()`. Make a demo or provide the proper html that would make that happen in notifications

Comment: I updated main post with html.. The problem is when I open list with notifications and try to click on some link of notification it just close list not redirect to correct link...

Comment: Really can't help more without a demo that replicates problem in plnkr.co to be able to see events in dev tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need a custom blur directive to handle events on a separate notification container. Something along these lines:

```
directive('customBlur', function(){
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    'customBlur': '='
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    element.on('click', function(event){
      var targetAttr = angular.element(event.target).attr('custom-blur')
      if (typeof targetAttr !== 'undefined' && scope.customBlur) {
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.customBlur = false;
        });
      } 
    });
  }
}});
```

Here is a working [plukner](http://plnkr.co/edit/8VbFRkiiAc98PIsQRhOZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, how  to implement this in my example?

Comment: Problem now is that it will not close if I click outside div fit notifications...

Comment: @VladimirDjukic - please adapt the example I have provided into your design/code. I can't help you more than that!

Answer (score 0):

Description given in [W3 specification docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget),

> **blur**
>
> The blur event occurs when an element loses focus either via the pointing device or by tabbing navigation. This event is valid for the following elements:
>
> LABEL, INPUT, SELECT, TEXTAREA, and BUTTON.
>
> Bubbles: No
>
> Cancelable: No
>
> Context Info: None

It will give you unpredictable output for other tags. If you have noticed, div tag doesn't capture focus hence no blur event.

But if you want to use event like blur, you can create custom directive which can be combinations of these four events DOMFocusOut, DOMFocusIn, mouseenter or mouseover, mouseleave.